# Android, ListView Searching/Filter -> Duplicate entries

Tags: android, search, listview, filter

AS the title explains, I'm having trouble with filtering/searching my listview. When I try to search for lets say "A", the listView displays A-31 two times, A-32 two times and so on. Does anyone have an idea why this occurs?

```
package hpliu.grupp2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TableRow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SearchRoomActivity extends ListActivity {
    private EditText filterText = null;
    SimpleAdapter menu = null;
    ListView lv = null;

    static final String[] AHalls = new String[] { "A-31", "A-32", "A-33",
            "A-34", "A-35", "A-36", "A-37" };

    String[] from = new String[] { "roomName", "buildingName" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_room);

        createCampusList("Campus Valla, Linköping",
                createHashMap(AHalls, "A Huset"));

        // filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
        // filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    }

    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            menu.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

    };

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> toHash = (HashMap<String, String>) this
                    .getListAdapter().getItem(position); // {text1 = "A-31",
                                                            // text2 = "Herp"};

            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Searching for... " + " "
                            + toHash.get("roomName").toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> createHashMap(String[] Halls,
            String Building) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Halls.length; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(from[0], Halls[i]);
            map.put(from[1], Building);
            fillMaps.add(map);
        }
        return fillMaps;
    }

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> createHashMap(String[] Halls,
            String[] Buildings) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Halls.length; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(from[0], Halls[i]);
            map.put(from[1], Buildings[i]);
            fillMaps.add(map);
        }
        return fillMaps;
    }

    public void createCampusList(String campusHeader,
            List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps) {

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.roomName, R.id.buildingName };

        menu = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
        setListAdapter(menu);
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you filter an adapter that has two strings in each item the filter will pass through the adapter twice. This is why you have multiples.  If you had three strings in each you could possibly get three duplicate items.

One solution I found online was to create a custom SimpleAdapter and check for duplicates before populating your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

My custom listview faced the same problem.

The superclass of listview doesn't know that you've changed the size when you have filtered. This means getCount() will return the original size of the array, which is understandably larger than your filtered array. So you must override getCount() function to return the size of filtered array, not the original array. After that, duplicated items gone.

```
@Override    
public int getCount() {
    return filter_array.size();
    }
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filter_array.get(position);
    }
```